# How can I save a group of Direct2D bitmaps to a dynamic image file?

Tags: c++, direct2d, wic, image-file

recently, I'm disturbed by saving bitmap to dynamic image file. I want to turn a group of bitmaps into a dynamic image file, but the function *IWICBitmapFrameEncode::WriteSource* **only cover the previous frame** while writing a new frame to file, and **it makes the image file failed (the file is a static image)**. How can I solve the problem?

In addition, perhaps I haven't explained clearly , the following photo will help you understand:

[the example of "dynamic image file", result of Program output. this image is **dynamic and multiframe** (GIF)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xWeYd.gif)

[the example of "static image",
the Direct2D Bitmap which has been read into the memory of application. this image is **singleframe** (JPEG)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cYTkt.png)

Comment: What is a "dynamic image file"? what is a "static image"?

Comment: I have edited my question……Would you do me a favor? Thank you☺️☺️☺️

Comment: You must call CreateNewFrame multiple times. Here's an example here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62956147/encoding-animated-gif-with-wic-imaging-component-infinite-loop

Comment: Only a few of the WIC built-in codecs support multi-frame images: ``gif`` and ``tiff``.